# Get ServiceStack session in MVC.Net attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, servicestack

I'm using MVC.Net and servicestack with AuthFeature

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(),
                new IAuthProvider[]
                {
                    new CredentialsAuthProvider()
                })
                {   IncludeRegistrationService = true });
```

I want to do a MVC.NET filter or attribute to make some validation and redirection before action methods execute, but i need the user session to do it.

```
public class UserConfirmationAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        //Get service stack user session
    }
}
```

In a service or controller is easy to get the session, only have to use `SessionAs<AuthUserSession>()`. How can I get service stack user session inside a MVC.Net Attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your FilterAttribute is for an action on a MVC Controller inheriting from `ServiceStackController` you can resolve it from the Controller with:

```
var ssController = filterContext.Controller as ServiceStackController;
var session = ssController.ServiceStackProvider.SessionAs<AuthUserSession>();
```

Otherwise you can get the session from a new `ServiceStackProvider` instance with:

```
var ssProvider = new ServiceStackProvider(filterContext.HttpContext.ToRequest());
var session = ssProvider.SessionAs<AuthUserSession>();
```